# How to make multiple radio button group checked

Tags: css, css-selectors, radio-button

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hvz2nky7/

CSS:

```
.radio-tile-group {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.radio-tile-group .input-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 3rem;
    width: 7rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
}
.radio-tile-group .input-container .radio-button {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.radio-tile-group .input-container .radio-tile {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 1rem;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
}
.radio-tile-group .input-container .radio-tile-label {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #000;
}
.radio-tile-group .input-container .radio-button:checked ~ .radio-tile {
    background-color: #000;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
.radio-tile-group .input-container .radio-button:checked ~ .radio-tile .radio-tile-label {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

The code only checks the last radio... How can I modify so it checks each group individually?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

Radiobuttons are grouping by the `name` attribute.

```html
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="r1">
<label for="r1">daily</label>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="r2">
<label for="r2">monthly</label>

<br>

<input type="radio" name="group2" id="r3">
<label for="r3">daily</label>
<input type="radio" name="group2" id="r4">
<label for="r4">monthly</label>

<br>

<input type="radio" name="group3" id="r5">
<label for="r5">daily</label>
<input type="radio" name="group3" id="r6">
<label for="r6">monthly</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons allow a user to select a single option among multiple options. So if you want to choose multiple option it's better to use checkbox instead radio buttons, this allow you to choose multiple things at the same time

Comment: No they are placed in different section of the page.